# Microwave detection circuit verification

Tags: electromagnetic, microwave, detector, sensing

I want to develop a circuit which can detect electromagnetic waves (radio wave, microwaves.)

This circuit will just act as a tamper detect and not physically measure/compute the radiation.

I have designed the circuit using a toroid ring and a few Schottky diodes.

The calculation formulas and schematic diagram are in the attachment.

After testing the circuit, I'm not getting any output.

Hence, I wanted to get the circuit as well as the calculation part of it verified.

Please note that the WAVE_SENSE signal in the design is connected to a 10-bit ADC of a microcontroller.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you expecting the coil to receive microwaves?  If so, you can give up on that.  It won't work at the frequencies you are interested in.

Comment: Toroids are closed loops, they tend to cancel outside fields. ie. they do not make good antennas.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your coil won't be responsive at the frequencies you are interested in.  I don't have the math to figure it, but I have some experience as a technician with radio frequency circuits.  That coil on that core will probably do a dandy job of filtering microwave signals **out** of your receiver.
2. Those diodes probably won't work at microwave frequencies, either.  The [BAT43 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85660/bat42.pdf) only mentions frequencies twice: 1MHz and 45MHz.  That diode isn't made for GHz frequencies like you will need to detect microwaves.

- You need a better diode.  I have used the [BAT63](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BAT63SERIES-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a304314dca38901151817843c0df4) for a similar project.
- You need an antenna instead of that coil.  I used a simple dipole antenna.  Just two equal length wires of approximately 1/4 the wavelength of the operating frequency you are interested in.

The circuit that I built used a sort of voltage multiplier to drive a few LEDs to indicate the RF level.

It looked like this:

[image]

You could simplify it to this:

[image]

Use two wires of about 3 centimeter length as antennas connected to P1 and P2.  3 centimeters is approximately correct for 2.5GHz.  That's about 1/4 the wavelength of 2.5GHz.

Comment: Thankyou JRE, Looks like a circuit worth testing.

Comment: @PralayPanchwate: Keep in mind that you can't build this on a solderless breadboard.  High frequency stufff does **not** play nice with solderless breadboards.  The BAT63 is purely a surface mount part, and you want to use surface mount parts for the capacitors as well.  I used size 0201 SMD capacitors for the 10pF parts.